# Excel: split cell in rows by new line

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-editing

Is there a way, in Excel, to split cell in rows by new line, like in the picture

[image]

PS.
Emily suggested me to copy to Word, however, when I copy it, it copies me like this:

```
6   A   B
7   "7A
7B" "7C
7D"
8   8C  "8C
8D"
9   9A  9B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will like to improve upon Emily's answer and be more elaborate doing the same, as she has been little too straightforward.

Copy the data:

[image: Data]

Go to MS Word and Press `Alt+Ctrl+V` and select **Formatted Text (RTF)**. Select the data and **copy**:
[image: copy from ms word]

Come back to MS Excel, select a cell and **Paste** using `Ctrl+V` and you'll get this:

[image: pasted in ms-excel]
Here, I have pasted the data in another sheet.

Click the cell containing **6**, *i.e.,* **A1** here, and click **Format Painter**.

[image: Format Painter]

Drag down the column containing the Numbers 6,7,8,9... to select all of them to format it properly.

[image: Final formatting]

Similarly, select the cell containing **6A**, click **Format Painter**, and drag down to get the desired format.

Thank you. I hope this detailed answer helps you with your problem :)

Comment: I couldn't get you. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I tested the case the 8C values is not in the first line, but on the second one (first line empty), then it should be in the bottom line, but it's the case :)

Answer (score 3):

Could you please use Word for assistant?

You can copy these data to Word, then copy these data back to Excel.

[image]

[image]

And then choose one cell, such as cell E3 that includes "6", use Format Painter to format cells for these data.

[image]

Comment: you should mention to use the formatted text, my excel, by example, pastes in the "only values" format :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use VBA, here is a macro that will do it:

```vba
Sub splitByNewLine()
    Dim pasteCell As Range, rowCumulationTotal As Integer
    rowCumulationTotal = 0
    
    On Error GoTo inputErrorHandling
        Set pasteCell = Range(InputBox("Please enter target cell address"))
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        Dim rowCumulationCurrent As Integer, maxElemsOnRow As Integer
        rowCumulationCurrent = 0
        maxElemsOnRow = 0
        For j = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
            Dim elems() As String, elemCount As Integer
            elems = Split(Cells(Selection.Row + i - 1, Selection.Column + j - 1), vbLf)
            elemCount = UBound(elems)
            For k = 0 To elemCount
                Cells(pasteCell.Row + i + rowCumulationTotal + k - 1, pasteCell.Column + j - 1) = elems(k)
                If maxElemsOnRow < k Then
                    rowCumulationCurrent = rowCumulationCurrent + 1
                    maxElemsOnRow = k
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
        rowCumulationTotal = rowCumulationTotal + rowCumulationCurrent
    Next i
    Exit Sub
    
inputErrorHandling:
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox ("You didn't enter valid cell address")
End Sub
```

To use it, just **select the area** that you want to convert and run the macro. It will ask you for a target cell, which is a cell where the selection will be copied (or rather where the copying will start) with the required splitting.

Comment: bogues when the target cell is the top left selection cell (if I want to replace the existing data), but it's not bad as is, thanks!